# Angular Material 2 Textarea Autosize Attribute (mdTextareaAutosize)

Tags: angular, textarea, angular-material2

I am using `@angular/material@2.0.0-beta.2`. I have textarea with `mdTextareaAutosize` attribute in container with `display:none` (popup).
I call `setValue` method of angular form control. When I open popup the textarea has `height:0px` and initial value is not shown. When I click on the textarea and press any key the initial value appears.

If I add boolean condition to show textarea (*ngIf) and make this condition as true in 2 seconds then it works. But without `timeout` it does not work.

Comment: It is a very specific question and some code would go nicely along with that.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem, the textareaAutosize calculate the height before the new value is displayed.

To fix this, you can use `resizeToFitContent(true)` function.
it force the autosize to recalculate the height (the boolean parameter is to force the calculation event if the content did not change).

I don't know if this existed for angular material 2. I use material 6.